# Symfony access prototype data in a Collection

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I am stuck with an issue I cant seem to fix yet , I am trying to edit some bidirectional Many->Many relations in a form using a Collection .

It seems that none of my prototype entries are saved upon submitting , and only changes done on initial relations would be taken into account .

Here is some of my code :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $item = $builder->getData();
    $builder
        ->add('serviceCol', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ServiceType::class,
            'entry_options' => array('label' => false,),
            'property_path' => 'service',
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
            'delete_empty' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
            'data' => $item->getService()))
    ;
}
```

subform :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $service = $event->getData();

            $form->add('service', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Service::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->orderBy('s.id_service', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'property_path' => 'nom',
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => false,
                'data' => $service,
                'placeholder' => 'Aucun'));

        });
}
```

entity - mappedBy :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Service", mappedBy="applis")
 */
private $services;

public function __construct() {
    $this->services = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addService( Service $service = null ): bool {
    if ($this->services->contains($service)) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->services[] = $service;
    return true;
}
public function remService( Service $service): bool {
    return $this->services->removeElement($service);
}

public function getService() {
    return $this->services;
}
```

entity - possessing :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Appli", inversedBy="services" )
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="service_to_app",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="services", referencedColumnName="id_service")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="applis", referencedColumnName="id_apps")}
 *      )
 */
private $applis;

public function __construct() {
    $this->applis = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function addApp( Appli $app): bool {
    //$app->addService($this);
    if ($this->applis->contains($app)) {
        return false;
    }
    $this->applis[] = $app;
    return true;
}
public function remApp( Appli $app){
    if ($app->remService($this)){
        return $this->applis->removeElement($app);
    }
    return false;
}

public function getApp(){
    return $this->applis;
}
```

`dump($form->all())` doesnt even show anything about my prototypes ..
is there something I can do to retrieve those informations before they disappear , in POST_SUBMIT event or anything ?

Edit: Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // On récupère la balise <div> en question qui contient l'attribut « data-prototype » qui nous intéresse.
        var $container = $('div#appli_form_serviceCol');

        // On définit un compteur unique pour nommer les champs qu'on va ajouter dynamiquement
        var index = $container.find(':input').length;
        var $button = $('#add_field');
        $button.click(function(e) {
            addField($container);
            //test();
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });

        if (index == 0) {
            addService($container);
        } else {
            $container.children('div').each(function() {
                addDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        }

        function addField($container) {

            var template = $container.attr('data-prototype')
                .replace(/__name__label__/g, 'service n°' + (index+1))
                .replace(/__name__/g, index)
            ;

            var $prototype = $(template);

            addDeleteLink($prototype);

            $container.append($prototype);

            index++;
            console.debug( $prototype);
        }

        function addDeleteLink($prototype) {
            var $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn-danger"><button class="delButton">Supprimer</button></a>');

            $prototype.append($deleteLink);

            $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
                $prototype.remove();
                e.preventDefault(); 
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
```

Let me know If there is any relevant code parts I did forget .

Comment: I think you've forgotten to add a getter for the entity.  public function getService() { echo 'getting a collection'; } I can post it as an answer, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: right , I'm adding access methods in edit .

Comment: as well, you need to have a method addService(), read this article https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: it would be easier to use xdebug to check this out.

Comment: I also added my javascript which I suspect could be the cause , I cant get to find anything out of those xdebug traces .

Comment: I figured out that prototypes values are saved whenever my collection starts empty . make it 2 different collections as a bad workaround .